# cygwin gdb still not work even after installed

Tags: c#, c, cygwin, clion

I have already installed cygwin and also add the bin folder to Path, but in Clion Debugger, it still said not found please install the package, anyone has idea?
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhROq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJDDX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need more than just Cygwin to use the GDB in CLion. You also need to install gcc-g++ and make along with GDB within the Cygwin setup utility. Step by step instructions on how to do so are here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html